# Python: How can I extract those Address ID including 'ACT' from this turtle file?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, rdf

I am really new to Semantic Web and I want to extract those address id including 'ACT' from this webpage first and then save the info under the links to a RDF structure and then save them to a database for future use.

Here are my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

url='http://gnafld.net/address/?page=7&per_page=10'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

After I run the code, I got the following answer:

```
@prefix ldp: <http: ldp#="" ns="" www.w3.org=""> .
@prefix rdf: <http: 02="" 1999="" 22-rdf-syntax-ns#="" www.w3.org=""> .
@prefix rdfs: <http: 01="" 2000="" rdf-schema#="" www.w3.org=""> .
@prefix reg: <http: linked-data="" purl.org="" registry#=""> .
@prefix xhv: <https: 1999="" vocab#="" www.w3.org="" xhtml=""> .
@prefix xml: <http: 1998="" namespace="" www.w3.org="" xml=""> .
@prefix xsd: <http: 2001="" www.w3.org="" xmlschema#=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846009="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846009"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846010="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846010"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846013="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846013"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846014="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846014"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846015="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846015"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846016="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846016"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846017="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846017"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846018="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846018"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846019="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846019"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gaact714846020="" gnafld.net=""> a <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    rdfs:label "Address ID: GAACT714846020"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:register <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: address="" gnafld.net=""></http:> a reg:Register ;
    rdfs:label "Address Register"^^xsd:string ;
    reg:containedItemClass <http: def="" gnaf#address="" gnafld.net=""> .

<http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=7" address="" gnafld.net=""> a ldp:Page ;
    ldp:pageOf <http: address="" gnafld.net=""></http:> ;
    xhv:first <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=1" address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    xhv:last <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=1450001" address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    xhv:next <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=8" address="" gnafld.net=""> ;
    xhv:prev <http: ?per_page="10&amp;page=6" address="" gnafld.net=""> .

</http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></http:></https:></http:></http:></http:></http:>
```

How can I extract those Address ID including 'ACT' from it? I know if I want to use Beautifulsoup, I need a html format. But it returns a turtle format. OR how can I change the turtle format to html format? (like change some parameters in requests() or Beautifulsoup()?) I am really stuck..Can anyone give me any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like this

```
import re
import requests

url = 'http://gnafld.net/address/?page=7&per_page=10'
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
results = re.findall('\"Address ID: (GAACT[0-9]+)\"', response.text)
```

The results list will contain the ids. If you don't want the `GA` at the beginning of the id you can change the last line to.

```
results = re.findall('\"Address ID: GA(ACT[0-9]+)\"', response.text)
```

This looks for all non overlapping strings of the form `"Address ID: GAACT[0-9]+"`. The `[0-9]+` is looking for any string of numbers of length at least one. The string in parentheses is captured and returned as a result. Thats's why you get just the id (e.g. `GAACT714846020`) and not the whole string (e.g.`"Address ID: GAACT714846020"`). Moving the `GA` out of the parentheses removes it from the result.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for this called RDFLib, no BeautifulSoup or Regex required. (`pip install rdflib`) It's all about reading and querying RDF data, including turtle format.

To get started:

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse('http://gnafld.net/address/?page=7&per_page=10')
```

This will load that turtle data into something that can be queried. You can use SPARQL to query it, to get those addresses:

```
res = g.query("""SELECT ?subject ?add 
              WHERE {
                 ?subject a <http://gnafld.net/def/gnaf#Address>.
                 ?subject rdfs:label ?add.
              }""")
for row in res:
    print(row.subject, row.add)
```

A SPARQL query can be used to access any of the data in their you need. You may also be able to use RDFLib to parse the data in the new links if it is also RDF.

What I think you'll be wanting to do is:

```
for row in res:
    g.parse(row.subject)
```

This will get all the data from those subjects into RDF format. From there you can save it in RDF as a file using:

```
g.serialize("my_data.rdf", format="pretty-xml")
```

Or carry on running queries with SPARQL.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But any idea how can i save it to a SPARQL endpoint on Fuseki Server? And if I use g.serialize("my_data.rdf", format="pretty-xml"), where can i find out the file 'my_data.rdf'?

Comment: In the same directory as you ran your Python. You can put a whole file path there to specify where you want it. I haven't used Fuseki, but I'm sure it must have some facility to invest and rdf file.